# Как добавить статическое свойство объекту JS (функция)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить свойство объекта из самой функции. Грубо `handler.get_elem = $elem;` этот кусок запихнуть в саму функцию, так чтобы вызов остался тем же. 
`handler(result)` и `handler.get_elem => $elem`.

```
var $elem,
handler = function(result) {
    $('#some_elem').insertAfter($elem);
    $('div.img_del').on('click', function() {
        delUserImage($(this));
    });
    $elem.css('color', result);
};
handler.get_elem = $elem;
```

Видимо и впрямь непонятно написал. Чего Хочу: есть некая функция которая принимает handler.

```
function query_ajax(obj, handler){
  var query  = '';
  $.each(obj, function (key, value){
    if(query.length !== 0) query += '&';
    query += key + '=' + value;
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/resp/' + query,
    data: query,
    beforeSend: function (){
        if(handler.get_elem){
            handler.get_elem.css('cursor', 'progress');
            handler.get_elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

    },
    success: function(data){
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
            handler.get_elem.css('cursor', 'auto');
            handler.get_elem.removeAttr('disabled');
        if(result) {
            handler(result);
        }
        else{

        }


    },
    error: function(){
        handler.get_elem.css('cursor', 'auto');
        handler.get_elem.removeAttr('disabled');

    }
  }); 
}
```

в ней идет обращение к свойству handler.get_elem.css('cursor', 'auto');
А непонятно мне как handler.get_elem = $elem; внести в  handler = function(result) { сюда вобщем }

Comment: ничего не понятно что вы хотите получить? какой объект имеется ввиду? Что понимаете по _статически_ свойством?

Comment: Я все больше и больше понимаю, как люди усложняют сами себе жизнь :) А по теме, распишите точнее, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. Так и не понял что хотите. Функции **могут** иметь свойства, т. к. это объекты в `JS`. Назначьте значение и обращайтесь к нему.

Comment: так и обращайся `handler.get_elem` вместо `$elem`

Comment: Так я то к handler.get_elem и обращаюсь, но сначала то ему нужно присвоить $elem. Меня попросту коробит дописывать это  handler.get_elem = $elem;  после объявления. Вот и спрашиваю как его внести внутрь function(){}

Comment: а что это за $elem? как вариант передавать параметром, как советуют в ответе

Comment: Разные функции получают разные объекты $elem. Немного раньше (var поставил чтоб не переписывать все). Параметром передавать тоже не хочеться поскольку этих элемов можно к хендреру понавешать сколь угодна а параметр каждый раз расширять не очень интересно

Comment: вот как раз передавать параметром самое простое решение. Но на данный момент вопрос слишком неконкретен. Не понял эту фразу _поскольку этих элемов можно к хендреру понавешать сколь угодна а параметр каждый раз расширять не очень интересно_. Добавьте в вопрос больше примеров использования `handler`, а так же примеров заполнения elem. Кроме того посмотрите, как написать [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно люди пишут в комментах, не усложняйте себе жизнь, делайте просто:

```
var handler = function(result, elem) {
    $('#some_elem').insertAfter(elem);
    $('div.img_del').on('click', function() {
        delUserImage($(this));
    });
    elem.css('color', result);
};

handler($result, $elem);
```

Comment: где `css` вызывается забыл $ убрать

Comment: @Grundy, ага, поправил